# Appended list with dictionaries has the same value. BeatifulSoup data

Tags: python-3.x, list, beautifulsoup, append

I want to pull data from a website and to build a list with dictionaries out of it.

```py
item = {"price": "", "price per gramm": ""}
list_of_sku = []


soup = BeautifulSoup(open("./FULL_data.html"), "html.parser")

for divs in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "col-xs-6 col-sm-4"})[:2]:
    links = divs.find_all("tr")
    for row in links:
        # We get list of prices here
        item_text = row.find('td')
        if item_text:
            item["price"] = str(item_text.text)
            print(item["price"])
            list_of_sku.append(item)
    print(list_of_sku)
```

As a result, I get an appended list, but all the prices in a row are the same.

```
/PycharmProjects/MyFirstOne/WEBSCRAPING/Work with Soup data.py" 

$125.70   [{'price': '$125.70', 'price per gramm': ''}]  

$35.70  [{'price': '$35.70', 'price per gramm': ''}, {'price': '$35.70', 'price per gramm': ''}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Without seeing your HTML, it's difficult to help. Please create a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are modifying the "item" object each time and reinserting it. Try moving the first line into the loop:

```
list_of_sku = []

with open('./FULL_data.html', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("./FULL_data.html"), "html.parser")

for divs in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "col-xs-6 col-sm-4"})[:2]:
    links = divs.find_all("tr")
    for row in links:
        # We get list of prices here
        item_text = row.find('td')
        if item_text:
            item = {"price": "", "price per gramm": ""}
            item["price"] = str(item_text.text)
            print(item["price"])
            list_of_sku.append(item)
    print(list_of_sku)
```